# Is there a way to use the string interpolation technique for setting a specific viper key that holds a list?

Tags: go, viper-go

I am trying to use viper to set a particular property. I am aware of the convenience syntax that allows setting a viper configuration property by using the "dot" notation to reference nested properties.

```
viper.Set("something.else.list[0].property", "value")
```

However when I try to do the same for a property which contains a list of nested properties (as above), it does not work. It treats `[0]` or `[%d]` as string (which makes sense), and ends up creating `"list[0]"` as a key under the `else` key.

How can I set a particular element of the array using this convention?

Comment: key can't be list/slice. it should be in valid map/json format

Comment: You need to try ```viper.Set("something.else.list", []map[string]string{{"property": "value"}})```